# Graphics application just shows blank screen

Tags: java, swing

I try to write a code to draw a Oval run from the top left down to the bottom right. But when I run to program, it show the blank screen on app.
Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleAnimation {
    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++){
            x++;
            y++;

            drawPanel.repaint();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    } // close go() method

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
        @Override
        public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    } // close inner class
} // close outer class
```

Comment: You seem to have overridden `paintComponents` instead of `paintComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Override `paintComponent()` instead of `paintComponents()`.

So change the `public void paintComponents() {...}` to `public void paintComponent() {...}`

But just for the hint:

Try to use Timers instead of Threads. Always try not to mess with the swing thread. In your case you can use javax.swing.Timer to call the repaint in 50 ms intervals:

```
counter = 0;
t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(counter>=130)
            t.stop();

        counter++;
        x++;
        y++;
        drawPanel.repaint();
    }
});
t.start();
```

`javax.swing.Timer t` and `int counter` are member variables for your class.

Good Luck.

Comment: I don't think that is problem, I am able to compile and run it successfully with `paintComponents` method.

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia: you are calling paintComponents() directly. and you have to pass Graphics as the argument which I don't prefer to. If you want to just call repaint() you should override paintComponent() instead. Also overriding paintComponent(), you do not need to call super.paintComponents() or so.

Comment: yes, you may be right, but I have just tried to answer with more related to PO's approach.

Comment: @user3344172: Your welcome. Typically when an answer solves your problem you may mark it as the solution (Green Check mark near the asnwer).

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `super.paintComponent(g);` and also you  need to call `paintComponents` rather than `repaint` method. Please try it with below code. I hope it helps :)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SimpleAnimation {
  int x = 70;
  int y = 70;

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
    gui.go();
  }

  public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);



    for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
      x++;
      y++;

      drawPanel.paintComponents(drawPanel.getGraphics());

      try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }
  } // close go() method

  class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.paintComponent(g); 
      g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
      g.setColor(Color.green);
      g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
    }
  } // close inner class
} // close outer class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :). I just need change paintComponents to paintComponent and than it's work for me.